Why does Ubuntu take over a minute to wake up?
My Ubuntu 24.04 LTS takes over a minute to wake up from sleep. Bazzite, which I run as dual boot on the system, is there in a manner of seconds. So I am fairly certain the hardware (GPD Win Max 2) can handle it.
Question being, why does Ubuntu take so much longer? And where would I need to start looking?
EDIT: One more thing of note - if I wake the laptop in the first five minutes or so after sending it to sleep, the wakeup takes only a few seconds (just like on Bazzite). Is it possible that Ubuntu goes into a deeper sleep after a while?

OS: Ubuntu 24.04 LTS (Wayland)
Kernel: 6.8.0-36-generic
APU: AMD Ryzen 7 8840U with Radeon 780M
RAM: 64 GiB
Disk Capacity: 2 TB


You are comparing a light weight gaming platform to a full featured OS. Like asking why your apples do not give orange juice.

I'm unsure how to determine the "weight" of an OS, but Bazzite is built on top of Fedora and in addition to the gaming platform is also a fully featured OS. So I don't think it's that easy.

Do you have an SSD or HDD?

M.2 SSD with PCIe 4.0.

Are you booting or waking from sleep?

might want to look at systemd-analyze

When I researched it it never said built on top of. It said modeled after. Anyway good luck.

@user10489 Waking from sleep. How can I use systemd-analyze for wake up? It seems to only return Startup times.

Ok, waking from sleep or waking from hibernation?  If the latter, it has to load the previous memory image from disk.  If the former, possibly some device driver is taking a long time to wake up.  Either way, systemd-analyze won't be much help, sorry.  Maybe check kernel messages.

How would I determine if the machine is in sleep or hibernation? The power menu item is just called suspend.
